# convert stdclass object array to json correct

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

Sorry for my English, I need help I want to convert a query which will return this.

```
{"ids":"1","user":"aki","last":"terris","job":"programmer"}{"ids":"1","user":"ako","last":"acros","job":"Artist"}
```

Change it to

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "user": "aki",
      "last": "terris",
      "job": "programmer"
    },
    {
      "user": "ako",
      "last": "acros",
      "job": "Artist"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with while, foreach but none gives me a valid format, some help

consult:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_s WHERE ids = '1' ");    
$set_users = $sql;
```

Ex :

```
$entity = array();    
while ($get_users = $set_users->fetch_object()) {

    $entity = array(
        'id' => $get_users->id,
        'user' => $get_users->user
        );

}

$fsi = array(
    'users' => $entity, 
    );

echo $fsi;
```

Comment: can you show your wile loop code through which you get your original json data?

Comment: SELECT only the columns you want, loop and add each row to an array, then `json_encode` the array.

Comment: while ($get_users = $set_users->fetch_object()) {

 echo $get_users;

}

Comment: I'm trying with fetch_object

Comment: You don't need an object as `json_encode` will turn those arrays into objects.

Comment: please post that full code into your question by editing it

Comment: In a moment I add

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$results = new \stdClass;
$results->users = [];

while ($get_users = $set_users->fetch_object()) {

    $entity = array(
        'user' => $get_users->user,
        'last' => $get_users->last,
        'job'  =>  $get_users->job,
    );
    $results->users[] = $entity;
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch_all` with the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` option, to get data immediately in the desired format, i.e. as an associative array which will render JSON object notation when converted with `json_encode`:

```
$fsi = [ 'users' => $set_users->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ];    
echo json_encode($fsi);
```

Make sure to use an SQL query that only selects the fields that you want to end up in the JSON.